# das Wörtchen "wieweil"

Tags: etymology

Aus meiner Lektüre älterer Texte in Zusammenhang mit meinem merkwürdigen Sinn für Sprachästhetik meine ich, dass mir schon das eine oder andere Mal das Wort "wieweil" begegnet ist. 
Ein schönes Wort, und eigentlich im deutsch-sprachigen Sinne ein sehr deutsches Wort.

Komischerweise findet es sich in keinem Duden oder wiktionary. Andere "obsolete" Worte wie allfällig, zuvorderst etc. findet man ja auch, obwohl sie sich nicht im gängigen Alltagswortschatz 2018 befinden.
Wo ist hier der Fehler? Ist es zu alt? Ist es der unseligen Rechtschreibreform qua Trennung zum Opfer gefallen (wieweil => wie weil)? Wer weiß was? Bin ich hier auf dem Irrweg und gibt es das Wort am Ende gar nicht?

Comment: Hast Du vielleicht einen Beispielsatz aus Deiner Lektüre parat (am besten mit Quellenangabe)? Mich erinnert es spontan an [alldieweil](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/alldieweil), wird/wurde es vielleicht ähnlich gebraucht?

Comment: Ich kenne "alldieweil" und ds war's dann - "wieweil" ist mir noch nicht begegnet, trotzdem, dass ich Bücher lese, die "nicht ganz neu" sind.

Comment: Es gibt/gab auch noch [dieweil](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dieweil), was ähnlich klingt.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass du es mit _wiewohl_ verwechselst, das übrigens zu meinen Lieblingswörtern gehört.

Comment: @tofro: Bitte "obwohl ich Bücher lese", nicht "trotzdem, dass ich".

Comment: @userunknown an "trotzdem, dass" ist m.A. nach überhaupt nichts falsch.

Comment: @tofro: Leider bist Du da nicht der Einzige. Ich dachte es sei hier auch schon eine Frage gewesen, finde sie aber nicht.

Comment: @userunknown "Trotzdem ich Bücher lese" (ohne dass, also als Konjunktion) wäre definitiv falsch/umgangssprachlich (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/trotzdem_obzwar_wenngleich). Mit "dass" ist es mAn richtig.

Comment: "Ich lese alte Bücher und **trotzdem** ist es mir noch nicht begegnet" könnte man sagen (wenn man dafür ein fotografisches Gedächtnis hätte, oder sich wenig drum sorgt, ob stimmt, was man so verzapft). Oder "**Obwohl** ich alte Bücher lese ist es ..."

Answer (score 2):

Auch im DWB (alias Grimm-Wörterbuch) gibt es „wieweil“ nicht. Die entsprechenden Google-Hits scheinen alle bloss Scan-Fehler für „wieweit“ zu sein.

Comment: Mus muss nur richtig suchen, dann findet man hunderte Belege für die Existenz dieses Wortes.

Comment: Ich denke, dass es sich um einen aus einer irrtümlichen Vermischung von *wieweit* und *dieweil* enstandenen Neologismus handelt. Die allermeisten "Belege" dürften Forenbeiträge nicht näher bekannter Internetbenutzer sein. Wörterbücher kennen dieses Wort jedenfalls nicht. Das ÖWB steht leider nicht in meinem Bücherregal und es ist online nicht verfügbar.

Answer (score 1):

Gute Frage.

Mir ist das Wort auch geläufig, daher habe ich in der [Grundformliste des Institus für deutsche Sprache](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html) nachgesehen, in dem immerhin die 326.946 häufigsten deutschen Wörter (ohne Eigennamen) stehen. Zu meiner großen Verwunderung musste ich aber feststellen, dass das Wort *»wieweil«* in dieser Liste nicht enthalten ist.

Google muss man auch erst dazu überreden, genauer danach zu suchen (indem man die Wörter *»weisweil«* und *»wieviel«* aus der Suche ausschließt). Aber dann kommen doch Fundstellen zutage:

> 1
>   Die dringend notwendige, aber schwierige Aufgabe, zusammenzufassen, warum die Riots, **wieweil** sie nur eine Plünderei waren, doch auch ihre politische Bedeutung haben, übernahm keine geringere als Naomi Klein, zuerst in The Nation und dann als Wiederveröffentlichung, ebenfalls im Guardian.
>   *[fm4v3.orf.at](http://fm4v3.orf.at/stories/1686931/index.html)*
>
> 2
>   Sama na lustig,
>   **Wieweil** ma san jung!
>   Und an olti Goaß mocht jo
>   A oft no an Sprung.
>   *(Steirischer Dialekt)*
>   *[bar.wikipedia.org: Boarische Schreibweis](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarische_Schreibweis)*
>
> 3
>   Auch findet sich ein treues Fähnlein, nachhaltig des Dichterstreites, von Verehrern in der südafrikanischen Expositur, **wieweil** näher der Waidmannsdorfer Dichterschule.
>   *[de.wikipedia.org: Leopold Wagenhofer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Wagenhofer)*
>
> 4
>   **Wieweil** mir fehlt der Glaube.
>   *[Kommentar in hockeyfans.ch](http://www.hockeyfans.ch/ubbthreads/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=306005&page=5)*
>
> 5
>   Wer nach oben katapultiert wird und die Segnungen eines Leitenden empfängt, merkt bald, daß droben die Luft dünner (**wieweil** die Brieftasche dicker) und das Leben einsamer ist.
>   *[altesblog.zeit.de](http://altesblog.zeit.de/1977/06/ueberall-ist-cape-canaveral/seite-2)*
>
> 6
>   Und sie scheint immer noch zeitlos beliebt zu sein. **Wieweil** Motorroller scheinbar grundsätzlich ein Revival erleben:
>   [like-online.de](https://www.like-online.de/maschinen/zweiraeder/artikel/details/101623-vespa-primavera-es-leben-die-klassiker/)
>
> 7
>   Der Einflus des Strukturphasenübergangs bei 105° in SrTiO<sub>3</sub> auf das Leitungsband und die Fermioberfläche wurde kürzlich von Mattheiss berechnet. Es wird untersucht **wieweil** diese Ergebnisse zu einem mikroskopischen Verständnis der Supraleitung in SrTiO<sub>3</sub> beitragen.
>   *[sciencedirect.com](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0038109873906200)*

Google gibt an, *»ungefähr 1 550 Ergebnisse«* gefunden zu haben.

Das Wort ist offensichtlich nicht zu alt, es wird auch heute noch verwendet, wenn auch selten. Selbst wenn es der Rechtschreibreform zum Opfer gefallen wäre, würde man es dennoch bei einer Google-Suche häufiger finden.

Es fällt aber auf, dass es in unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen verwendet wird.

In 1, 3, 5 und 6 wird es als Synonym für *»obwohl«* verwendet, in 2 anstelle von *»derweil« (»solange«)* und in 4 als Ersatz für *»allein«*, das hier eine veraltete Form der Konjunktion *»doch«* ist (und somit semantisch in der Nähe von *»obwohl«*). In 7 ist es ein Synonym von *»inwiefern«*.

Meinem persönlichen Empfinden nach wurde *»wieweil«* im Beispiel 5 am passendsten verwendet.

Das Wort kann man auch im Ngram-Viewer von Google finden:
[image]
[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wieweil&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwieweil%3B%2Cc0)

*»Bin ich hier auf dem Irrweg?«* - Nein im Gegenteil: Ich finde es auch unerklärlich, warum dieses Wort in keinem Wörterbuch und in keiner Wortschatz-Sammlung zu finden ist.

Comment: Im Beispiel 7 wurde ein englischer Abstrakt ins Deutsche übersetzt, eventuell könnte sich dabei auch ein Fehler eingeschlichen haben und das *wieweil* ist unfreiwillig an dieser Stelle.

Comment: ... Eventuell nur ein Tippfehler, und gemeint war *wieweit* (Synonym zu *inwieweit*)

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Der deutsche Text ist eine relativ freie Übersetzung des englischen. Es gibt im englischen Text kein direktes Äquivalent für das deutsche »wieweil«. Wer an dieser Stelle anstatt *inwiefern* lieber *wieweil* schreibt, tut das wohl nur, weil er das *wieweil* an dieser Stelle für passend hält, es also bereits kennt, was mir als Beleg für die Existenz des Wortes (darum ging es in der Frage ja) ausreichend erscheint.

Comment: Aber selbst ohne diesen einen Text bleiben noch genügend andere Belege für die Existenz des Wortes.

Comment: Klar. Ich war nur drüber gestolpert, als ich versucht habe, aus Deinen Fundstellen was zur regionalen Verwendung abzuleiten. Und  bei deiner Auflistung der Bedeutungen fiel dieses Beispiel ja auch schon etwas raus.

Comment: Alle diese „Belege“ können als Fehler entweder für „wieweit“ oder für „wiewohl“ verstanden werden.

Comment: @fdb: Wie ich schon ganz zu Beginn sagte, ist mir dieses Wort durchaus bekannt. Außerdem kommt es ziemlich gleich häufig vor wie *»jütländisch«*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wieweil%2Cjütländisch&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwieweil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjütländisch%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Google Ngramme müssen hier mit Vorsicht interpretiert werden, denn sie sind nur so gut wie ihre Quelle. Wenn man [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wieweil%22&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQnszIt8HaAhWsxaYKHStLAacQpwUIIA&biw=1149&bih=565&dpr=1.1) durchsucht **und die angeblichen Funde selbst ansieht** wird man schnell merken, dass *wieweil* hier so gut wie immer eine "Erfindung" des Google-OCR-Scanners ist.

Comment: Selbst dieser Fund ist ein falsch zitiertes *derweil*: https://books.google.de/books?id=D1g3DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT528&dq=%22wieweil%22&pg=PT528#v=onepage&q=wieweil&f=false

Comment: @Takkat: Ja, das ist mir auch aufgefallen, daher habe ich auch ausschließlich Fundstellen zitiert, die NICHT aus gescannten Quellen stammen

Comment: Aber Du argumentierst, dass Du Dich wunderst warum *wieweil* in keinem Wörterbuch vorkommt, obwohl es über 1000 mal bei Google steht. Wir wundern uns doch auch nicht, dass trotz 99500 Funde in den Google Books  [**Oefierreich**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Oefierreich%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPr7ifv8HaAhUhBMAKHYqgDL0Q_AUIECgB&biw=1149&bih=565) auf keiner Karte vorkommt. Verschollener Geheimstaat aus dem 19. Jahrhundert vielleicht?

Comment: Wir werden dich als Botschafter ernennen.

Comment: Ich habe mal eine Frage auff ELU angestoßen zu einem etwaigen [how-while](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514118/is-howwhile-a-collocation?noredirect=1#comment1246619_514118). Viel scheint daraus nicht zu werden, doch die Verwendung von "since" als "weil", bzw "while" i.S.v. "obwohl" ist immerhin bemerkenswert, sowie dass "however" ursprünglich sehr *concessive*, also bestätigend, nicht widersprechend war. Schlaue Bemerkungen zu "während", "wäre, war", sowie "seit", ... "seid, sei" wollen  mir leider keine einfallen, die sich "wahr" anhören.